# Do objects pushed into an array in javascript deep or shallow copy?

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

Pretty self evident question...When using .push() on an array in javascript, is the object pushed into the array a pointer (shallow) or the actual object (deep) *regardless* of type.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

It depends upon what you're pushing.  Objects and arrays are pushed as a pointer to the original object .  Built-in primitive types like numbers or booleans are pushed as a copy.  So, since objects are not copied in any way, there's no deep or shallow copy for them.

Here's a working snippet that shows it:

```
var array = [];
var x = 4;
let y = {name: "test", type: "data", data: "2-27-2009"};

// primitive value pushes a copy of the value 4
array.push(x);                // push value of 4
x = 5;                        // change x to 5
console.log(array[0]);        // array still contains 4 because it's a copy

// object reference pushes a reference
array.push(y);                // put object y reference into the array
y.name = "foo";               // change y.name property
console.log(array[1].name);   // logs changed value "foo" because it's a reference    

// object reference pushes a reference but object can still be referred to even though original variable is no longer within scope
if (true) {
    let z = {name: "test", type: "data", data: "2-28-2019"};
    array.push(z);
}

console.log(array[2].name);   // log shows value "test" since the pointer reference via the array is still within scope
```

Comment: Nitpicking: every value is pushed *as a value*; in the case of objects those values just happen to be "pointers" to the object.

Answer (score 50):

jfriend00 is right on the mark here, but one small clarification: That doesn't mean you can't change what your variable is pointing to.  That is, `y` initially references some variable that you put into the array, but you can then take the variable named `y`, disconnect it from the object that's in the array now, and connect `y` (ie, **make it *reference***) something different entirely *without changing the object that now is referenced only by the array*.

http://jsfiddle.net/rufwork/5cNQr/6/

```
var array = [];
var x = 4;
var y = {name: "test", type: "data", data: "2-27-2009"};

// 1.) pushes a copy
array.push(x);
x = 5;
document.write(array[0] + "<br>");    // alerts 4 because it's a copy

// 2.) pushes a reference
array.push(y);
y.name = "foo";

// 3.) Disconnects y and points it at a new object
y = {}; 
y.name = 'bar';
document.write(array[1].name + ' :: ' + y.name + "<br>");   
// alerts "foo :: bar" because y was a reference, but then 
// the reference was moved to a new object while the 
// reference in the array stayed the same (referencing the 
// original object)

// 4.) Uses y's original reference, stored in the array,
// to access the old object.
array[1].name = 'foobar';
document.write(array[1].name + "<br>");
// alerts "foobar" because you used the array to point to 
// the object that was initially in y.
```

Comment: Interesting point about using `new` to "disconnect" the object reference.

Comment: Downvote explanation?  Hard to fix the issue if you don't let me know what it was.

Comment: Why ping me? I upvoted this a long time ago and did like your answer. Here is a screen of the vote: http://i.imgur.com/AnDt98c.png

Comment: Sorry @Travis -- collateral damage for SO not having another way for me to communicate with the recent anonymous downvoter that came by in the last week or two. I didn't expect it came from you, esp. with your positive comment. Sorry for the unfortunate spam your way, and thanks for staying on top of your question!

Comment: That was actually a misunderstanding on my part. My bad. Your comment showed in my notifications and I thought it was directed at me because I didn't realize that as the OP all comments show as notifications.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript: Create a Deep Copy of an Object in 2023

**Do NOT use `Object.assign()` in JavaScript to copy or clone objects!** It creates a shallow copy of your object and will assign deep objects to reference pointers in your copy!

You have *two choices*.

Use the older, more reliable `JSON` trick:

```
const obj1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(YourObject));
```

Or try the new & improved `structuredClone()` method. **Warning**: This only works for users who have updated their *evergreen* browsers since **2022**! No *Internet Explorer* or *Edge Trident* browser support!!

```
const obj2 = structuredClone(YourObject);
```