# Javascript Array Push Replaces Previous Element in The same Array

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am Facing this Problem, my `randomPoints` **array element is getting replaced** by push method. 
[Here is the output of my Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoSvI.png)

I don't know why this is happening but if I don't use `randomPoint.add`, it dosen't replaces and work fine.

`randomPoint.add` retuns the same Vector object as it would return without it.

```
var hw
var center
var randomPoints = []
var pointWidth = 20
var points = 300
centerCircleWidth = 300;
pointsOffset = 10

function setup(){
    hw = createVector(600,500)
    createCanvas(hw.x,hw.y)
    center = createVector(hw.x/2,hw.y/2)
    var randomPoint = createVector(0,0)
    randomPoints.push(randomPoint)
    randomPoint = p5.Vector.fromAngle(-radians(120), random(centerCircleWidth/2-pointWidth,centerCircleWidth/2-pointsOffset))
    randomPoints.push(randomPoint)
    console.log(randomPoint)
    randomPoint = randomPoint.add(p5.Vector.fromAngle(radians(60), random(pointsOffset,2*pointsOffset)))
    // this here replaces the last element of array by itself and add another element of same type.
    randomPoints.push(randomPoint)
    console.log(randomPoint)
    console.log(randomPoints)

}

function draw(){
    translate(center.x, center.y)
    background(51);
    strokeWeight(0)
    fill(255)
    ellipse(0,0, centerCircleWidth, centerCircleWidth)
    for(i=0;i<randomPoints.length;i++){
        fill(10)
        ellipse(randomPoints[i].x,randomPoints[i].y,pointWidth,pointWidth)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know the full code but I'm guessing here is where it gets interesting: `var randomPoint = createVector(0,0)`. Is that supposed to always refer to the same thing or is it supposed to refer to `new createVector(0,0)` because that looks like a constructor and if that's the case then you want to have a new one everytime or else you will override your old var reference,

Comment: Nope, because `createVector(0,0)` returns an object with `{x: 0,y: 0}`,  `p5.Vector.fromAngle()` and `randomPoint.add()` does the same

Comment: Okay got it, so why are you recycling the var then? Why not `let newRandomPt = p5.Vector.fromAngle(); randomPoints.push(newRandomPt);` and so on? It's 3 distinct vars, why then make a reference to it with the same var? That's hella confusing.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problems looks to be an object reference problem. The third `push` isn't replacing the previous element in the array, but you are updating the **reference** which the array is holding, therefore the element in the array is being updated.

If you remove the third `push`, you will see that the second item in the array will still be updated.

What you need to do is either create a copy of `randomPoint` and then make a change to it, or create a new variable.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8661088/4300608) SOF answer which should make it clearer.

Comment: Oh yes, That SOF answer was explained quite well and I've tried copying object and that worked !!.