# What is the reason why JS push objects by reference?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, pass-by-reference

What is the reason why Javascript push objects by reference and not by value?

And why this behavior is only for objects and not also for built-in primitives types?

For example:

```
let x = {a: 10, b: 100 }
let ar = [];

ar.push(x);
x.a = 9;
console.log(ar[0].a); // This print 9, not 10
```

I think an answer to this question is useful to understand some deep functions about this language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything in Javascript, not only primitives, is passed by value.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado check this post: 
[Do objects pushed into an array in javascript deep or shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660901/do-objects-pushed-into-an-array-in-javascript-deep-or-shallow-copy/8661088#8661088)

Comment: I know this, thanks anyway. It's still by value... It's complicated at first, I agree.

Comment: It's very difficult to do otherwise and still maintain some standard sense of object orientation.  If values were immutable and functions were free of side-effects, then this would be reasonable -- but then you're much of the way toward functional programming.  Javascript makes it easy enough to do OOP, and possible, but less easy to do FP; that was one of the essential design decisions of the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in JavaScript is passed by value...

But, those values can be a reference value.

The different seems subtle, but its very important.

For example, if you have a function:

```
function nukeArray(a) {
  a = [];
}
```

Then, when you call it, `a` will receive a value that happens to be a reference.  That value is immediately discarded and `a` is assigned a new reference.

If `a` was a pure reference, then changing `a` would also change the value of its caller.

In a language like `C` you can easily pass a reference -- change the reference -- then the caller's value will be changed as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void t(char **t) {
    *t = malloc(50);
}

int main() {
    char *tmp;
    printf("pre: %p\n", tmp);
    t(&tmp);
    printf("post: %p\n", tmp);
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is clear. But what about my example? If I change `x` object it will change also `ar[0]`. Isn't it like it's a reference?

Comment: Yes, it s a reference.  But a `reference value` -- meaning, it passes a value and that value is a reference.  This is *different* from passing by reference.  The real reason why you don't pass an object (or array) by value is that making a copy of that object would get expensive, which would slow down your program.

Comment: @Stefano if you don't want a reference to the original object you can always clone it (a shallow copy, probably) and push the cloned object.